# C# Cortana voice activation programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, cortana

I am trying to invoke Cortana programmatically.

I am already using this code to start Cortana

`await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("bing://home"));`

The problem is that in order to make a search you have to click the mic button in Cortana.

I want is that when Cortana starts the user should not be promted to press the mic button in order to make a search. As in Cortana starts listening whenever I want or at least when it opens up.

Is this possible? If so then how?

Answer (score 3):

It's highly unlikely, due to the privacy concerns with an app developer being able to arbitrarily start recording what the user is saying.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using ContinuousRecognitionSession on Windows 10.

```
private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;
private CoreDispatcher dispatcher;
private StringBuilder dictatedTextBuilder;

this.dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
this.speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult result =

await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();
speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated +=
ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;

private async void ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(
SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender,
SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
{

if (args.Result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.Medium ||
  args.Result.Confidence == SpeechRecognitionConfidence.High)
  {
    dictatedTextBuilder.Append(args.Result.Text + " ");

    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
      dictationTextBox.Text = dictatedTextBuilder.ToString();
      btnClearText.IsEnabled = true;
    });
  }
else
{
  await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
      dictationTextBox.Text = dictatedTextBuilder.ToString();
    });
}
}
```

Here is the complete [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn708067.aspx)

Considering integrate your app using Cortana on foreground too. Take a look [here](http://talkitbr.com/2015/07/13/integrando-a-cortana-em-seu-aplicativo-windows-10/)

Comment: Yes I am aware of the speechrecognizer and how to integrate Cortana in an app.
My requirement was different, I wanted to invoke Cortana through bluetooth or through another app. But She never starts listening on it's own unless the speaker button is pushed or more recently, you say "Hey Cortana!"